# Items on the Main Activity won't show up

Tags: java, android, xml

I just stuck with the issue, what I'm trying to do is the main activity first check for saved preferences on different activity and going back to continue the `setContentView()` and etc.

Register Activity works fine but when this activity want going back to main activity. The main Activity won't show up the ListView, Buttons and etc. just the action bar is visible.

I am not sure where is the problem, could someone help me on this.

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * default values.
     */
    if (Settings.isRegistered(this)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        this.startActivity(i);
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.Msg);

    messageList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**Msg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:hint="@string/message_edit_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatroom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:hint="@string/chatroom_text"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="@string/sendlabel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messagelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this part of your code at the end of `onCreate()`:

```
    /**
     * default values.
     */
    if (Settings.isRegistered(this)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
```

and of course without `return`

Answer (score 0):

Remove return statement after `startActivity`. And I recommend move `setContentView` to line below `super.onCreate`.

Comment: Thank you!///////////////////////////////